# How to count the number of characters in a textbox with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm writing a test suite with Capybara, and I need to test the length of a textbox in Ruby. It has a limit of 255 characters. Once the limit is reached you can't type anymore. So what I'm looking for is to count the number of characters that has been typed into the text box to ensure it doesnt exceed 255 characters. This is being done in Ruby (I've only started learning code so all new to me, any help would be great).

The :xpath /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[7]

I've researched a lot and all the code I can find is how to create a text box and to put a limit of the characters but I'm looking for code that can test that it works.

Stuff I've found like `a.count` or `content.count` but I cant get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; if you want to stop input on the client side you need to do this in JavaScript. (Technically, yes, you could do it with an Ajax call.) It's also not clear on what the XPath is for/being used by/etc.

Comment: Basically i have a comment box on a webpage that can hold 255 characters and once that limit is reached you cant type anymore so i looking for some code that can count the amount of characters that are in the comment box to ensure it doesnt exceed 255. Im looking to test the comment box, its already created and works its for testing (rspec).

Comment: Are you working in Ruby on Rails? If so, you have no access to the text field in Ruby. Ruby executes on the server, the text box only exists on the client-side. All you can manipulate server-side is the raw HTML, and that doesn't contain the text the user entered. That text is sent to your server by the client, and exists only as a string of characters in the `params` array.

Comment: Please clarify your question, as it stands it looks like you are trying to interact with the *client-side* browser in Ruby, which is a nonsensical thing to do. As a one rep user, most people will assume you do not understand how Rails works and that you are trying to do this anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby code can help you generate the textbox you need, but it won't track how the user is using it - at least not directly.  That's the job of the browser and the javascript you write to catch browser events.  And yes, you can catch each key press and send the result back to your server using AJAX so that you can process it in ruby, but why would you want to do any of this?

What you probably want is a ruby helper that can generate some html to tell the browser to limit the textbox input to a certain count.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
<%= text_box 'some_model', 'some_attribute' , :maxlength=>"255" %>
```

For text_area something like this:

```
<%= text_area 'some_model', 'some_attribute', 
  :onchange => "if (this.value.length > 255){ this.value = this.value.substr(0,255); }" %>
```

Or better yet, put that javascript in a helper .js file and add it using jQuery or the like.

**UPDATED**

To test the content length using RSpec/capybara with the xpath selector you provided:

```
find(:xpath, "/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[7]/textbox").value.length.should_be 255
```

Comment: If it's a textarea (not a standard one-line textbox) then the html maxlength attribute won't have any effect.  At that point, you'll have to rely on javascript as others have said - edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: I am looking to write an RSpec test that checks that the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the textbox is 255 character.

Comment: I am using capybara to check the client side during execution

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to use capybara to test that the textfield/area is indeed limiting the user input to 255 characters.  Is that it?

Comment: ive tried using that code find(:xpath, "/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[7]").value.length.should_be 255 but im getting an error saying NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didnt expect it! You might have expected an instance of array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.length. Any help to resolve this would be great.

Comment: Can you verify that the xpath selector is correct?  It's failing because .value is returning nil.  It might be simpler to tag it with a css (id, class) selector to leave less room for error.  Also, you might need to use page.find(...) or session.find(..) rather than just find().  See the RDoc for other ways that may suit you better - http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara

Comment: Hello PinnyM thanks for all your help. Ive managed to get it working now. Much appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Your very welcome.  I'd appreciate if you can flag this as answered - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late coming into this as I was searching for a similar solution.  I eventually came up with:

```
max_length = first(selector here).value

if max_length.length > 255
    puts 'Limit exceeds 255 characters - error'
else
    puts 'Limit is 255 characters - pass'
    end 
end
```

This counted the characters and output the correct message to console for me.  You can amend what's output to console to suit your test.

Or you could simplify it by using:

```
max_length = first(selector here).value

    expect(max_length.length). to eq 255
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
    expect(find('#element_id').value.length).to eq(255)
```